# get all the documents of a collection inside a QueryDocumentSnapshot

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwLVO.png)

/Info/Semestre1/Courses/course1 Is my full data base reference.
I'm trying to access all the courses name of all the semesters at ounce.

```
 db.collection("Courses").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {





                            }

                          // Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());



                        }



            }
        });


    }


I
```

I got all the semesters of Info. Now  how can I access all the courses names?

Comment: do you want to get the courses by semester, or it is fine for you to get all the courses not grouped?

Comment: I'm trying to get all semesters at ounce but i don't think it is possible maybe I will make the semester as a field for each course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your query in the question is actually incorrect.  Based on what I see in your screenshot, to get all the semesters, you would do this:

```
db.collection("Info").get()
```

Then, to get all the courses for a specific semester in the subcollection nested under the semester, you would need a whole new query like this:

```
String courseId = ...  // changes as you iterate the courses in Info
db.collection("Info").document(courseId).collection("Courses").get()
```

You can't get all the semesters and courses in one query with the database structure you have now.  Firestore queries are shallow, meaning they don't consider subcollections at all.  Each subcollection requires its own separate query.

Comment: so If i want all the courses at the same time the only way is to put the semester as a field of a certain course? It is not possible in this database design?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you saying you want all of the courses for all of the semesters in one query?

Comment: No, you just need a collection group query.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

Answer (score 3):

You are doing the same mistake which i done when i was learning more about firestore.

So the first mistake you are doing is directly accessing the "Courses" collection which

is not possible if you want to access the "Courses" collection then you must need to traverse through all the collection and document before it.

Ex :collection1/doc1/collection2/doc2/collection3

Now if you want to access the data of the collection3 then query for that is going to be like

collection1.doc().collection2.doc2().collection3.get() and then your listner thats just basic understanding before we move for you answer.

Now ans of you question

```
 db.collection("info").document("sem-id").collection(Courses).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {





                        }

                      // Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());



                   }

        }
    });


}
```

Let me know if still any doubt.Happy coding